# Set QLineEdit focus in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I am having a qt question. I want the QLineEdit widget to have the focus at application startup. Take the following code for example:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QPushButton>
#include <QtGui/QLineEdit>
#include <QtGui/QFont>


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QWidget *window = new QWidget();
     window->setWindowIcon(QIcon("qtest16.ico"));
     window->setWindowTitle("QtTest");

     QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(window);

     // Add some widgets.
     QLineEdit *line = new QLineEdit();

     QPushButton *hello = new QPushButton(window);
     hello->setText("Select all");
     hello->resize(150, 25);
     hello->setFont(QFont("Droid Sans Mono", 12, QFont::Normal));

     // Add the widgets to the layout.
     layout->addWidget(line);
     layout->addWidget(hello);

     line->setFocus();

     QObject::connect(hello, SIGNAL(clicked()), line, SLOT(selectAll()));
     QObject::connect(line, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), line, SLOT(selectAll()));

     window->show();
     return app.exec();
 }
```

Why does `line->setFocus()` sets the focus on the line widget @app startup only if it is placed after laying out the widgets and if used before it's not working?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Keyboard focus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/focus.html) is related to widget [tab order](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setTabOrder), and the default tab order *is based on the order in which widgets are constructed*. Therefore, creating more widgets changes the keyboard focus. That is why you must make the [`QWidget::setFocus`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus) call last.

I would consider using a sub-class of `QWidget` for your main window that overrides the [`showEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showEvent) virtual function and then sets keyboard focus to the `lineEdit`. This will have the effect of always giving the `lineEdit` focus when the window is shown.

Comment: Little correction: tab order is not the order in which the children are _constructed_, but the order in which they're _added_ to the parent.

Comment: That is probably true, but I was paraphrasing the Qt documentation taht states:
"You can customize the tab order using QWidget::setTabOrder(). (If you don't, Tab generally moves focus in the order of widget construction.)"

Answer (score 27):

Another trick that might work is by using the `singleshot` timer:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, line, SLOT(setFocus()));
```

Effectively, this invokes the `setFocus()` slot of the `QLineEdit` instance right after the event system is "free" to do so, i.e. sometime after the widget is completely constructed.

Comment: this worked like charm, the event system being free added to the advantage of properly focusing the newly(dynamically) created lineedit in mycase. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is an update as the last answer was in 2012 and the OP last edited the question in 2014.  They way I got this to work was to change the policy and then set the focus.

```
line->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
line->setFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Qt setFocus() is a slot, you can try other overloaded method which takes a Qt::FocusReason parameter like the line shown below:

```
line->setFocus(Qt::OtherFocusReason);
```

You can read about focus reason options in the following link:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qt.html#FocusReason-enum

Comment: Hi milot. Thanks for your answer. The thing is even if I change to what you wrote, it doesn't work. Since it's a widget slot I assume that I can connect a signal to it at application startup. Do you know which signal is that? Thanks again.

Comment: It can be any signal which it's signature is matched with the slot's one, so it can be connected to a signal which doesn't take any parameters.