# Qt trough PySide: QTextEdit doesn't get focus on window creation if there is a button in the window

Tags: python, qt, focus, pyside

```
I'm writing some code using Python 3.4, Qt 4.8.6 trough PySide 1.2.1.
```

I'm trying to get a custom Text Editor to work by using a QTextEdit and some QPushButton's, problem is: if there are QPushButtons in the Editor, QTextEdit doesn't get focused at window initialization, even if a explicit call to QTextEdit.setFocus() is made. If the buttons aren't included, all Just Works (TM), here is some code:

## Trouble Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class MyEditor(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyEditor, self).__init__()
        self.add_buttons()
        self.add_editor()

    def add_buttons(self):
        self.buttons_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.addLayout(self.buttons_layout)
        self.b1 = QPushButton('1')
        self.b2 = QPushButton('2')
        for b in (self.b1, self.b2):
            self.buttons_layout.addWidget(b)

    def add_editor(self):
        self.editor = QTextEdit()
        self.addWidget(self.editor)
        self.editor.setFocus()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.editor = MyEditor()
        self.setLayout(self.editor)
        self.show()

window = Window()
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

But if I don't include the Buttons (by commenting out the call to self.add_buttons), the QTextEdit gets focused just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class MyEditor(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyEditor, self).__init__()
        # self.add_buttons() <- Now focus works, but no buttons :(
        self.add_editor()

    def add_buttons(self):
        self.buttons_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.addLayout(self.buttons_layout)
        self.b1 = QPushButton('1')
        self.b2 = QPushButton('2')
        for b in (self.b1, self.b2):
            self.buttons_layout.addWidget(b)

    def add_editor(self):
        self.editor = QTextEdit()
        self.addWidget(self.editor)
        self.editor.setFocus()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.editor = MyEditor()
        self.setLayout(self.editor)
        self.show()

window = Window()
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

I deeply researched the PySide docs, google and etc. but no answer could be found, any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

PS.: Sorry about any mistakes in my English, I'm not a native of this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delaying the call to `setFocus` on the QTextEdit to after `setLayout` on QWidget has finished solves the problem. So I guess that setLayout changes the focus and one has to manually reset it afterwards. It might have to do with the tab order (see first answer in [Set QLineEdit focus in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526761/set-qlineedit-focus-in-qt)).

Here is your example with buttons and focus on the editor widget:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MyEditor(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyEditor, self).__init__()
        self.add_buttons()
        self.add_editor()

    def add_buttons(self):
        self.buttons_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.addLayout(self.buttons_layout)
        self.b1 = QPushButton('1')
        self.b2 = QPushButton('2')
        for b in (self.b1, self.b2):
            self.buttons_layout.addWidget(b)

    def add_editor(self):
        self.editor = QTextEdit()
        self.addWidget(self.editor)

    def set_focus(self):
        self.editor.setFocus()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.editor = MyEditor()
        self.setLayout(self.editor)
        self.editor.set_focus()
        self.show()

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Now it Just Works (TM) as it is intendend to do! Thank you very much! I will look into the link you sent.