# How can i get current focused QLineEdit in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, focus, qlineedit

How can I identify which `QLineEdit` has the current focus in qt?

To set the focus for `QLinEdit` I have tried:

```
   ui->linedit->setfocus();
```

but it also not working for me. How can I solve these two?

Answer (score 4):

To identify which focused Widget (QlineEdit or any QWidget), you need to get all your current widget children, cast each to QLineEdit,  and check which one has focus, sample code:

```
QList<QWidget*> mylineEdits = this->findChildren<QWidget*>();
QListIterator<QWidget*> it(mylineEdits); // iterate through the list of widgets
QWidget *lineEditField;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    lineEditField = it.next(); // take each widget in the list
    if(QLineEdit *lineE = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(lineEditField)) {  // check if iterated widget is of type QLineEdit
        //
        if (lineE->hasFocus())
          {
            // this has the focus ...   
          }

    }
}
```

Second issue, setting focus on QWidget, already answered in  this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526761/set-qlineedit-focus-in-qt):

Answer (score 2):

Set focus to a widget with `setFocus()` function.

```
ui->lineEdit_3->setFocus();
```

You can check focus on a widget using `hasFocus()` function.

```
QWidget * widgetName = qApp->focusWidget();
qDebug () << widgetName->objectName();
```

**output**: `"lineEdit_3"`

When the focused widget is changed `QApplication::focusChanged(QWidget *old, QWidget *now)` signal will be emitted. You can connect it to a slot where you do whatever you like based on the focus change.