# Force focus on popup

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I have a mainwindow and a button on this mainWindow that opens a popup.
Now I want to force the focus on that popup.

Right now i am doing

```
mainwindow.setEnabled(False)
popup.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

when the popup is opened and

```
mainwindow.setEnabled(True)
```

when the popup is closed, but that does not affect the focus.

Is there another way, than to catch the signal that the mainwindow got the focus and force it back to the popup?

Comment: Set `setFocus()` function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46702736/5068056

Comment: Have a look at QWidget windowModality for your "popup" class.

Comment: @ManuelH thanks I did not know about that, I thought it would be in a window flag.. solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment I was able to solve it myself (and it was quite easy):

```
popup.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
```

[link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop)